# Problem in Animation loop Java (Processing)

Tags: java, processing

I was able to create a simple loop of the ball moving from top left to bottom right, but I can't do the same for the top right to bottom left. Please help me solve this issue using the simple method I have used below, meaning don't use any advanced variables just keep it simple.//the repeating animation is working perfectly from top left to bottom right if u change it to (posX+1)%500, but the same thing is not happening for the top right to bottom left

```
int circleSize=50;
int posX=500 , posY=0;
void setup(){
  size(500,500);
}
void draw(){
  background(200);
ellipse(posX,posY,circleSize,circleSize);
 posX=(posX-1)%500;
posY=(posY+1)%500;
     println(mouseX,mouseY);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your logging to `println(posX,posY);` you'll see that the X coordinate goes negative and stays there, because -500 % 500 is 0, so you don't get back to your starting point.

Modify your sketch by adding:

```
if (posX <= 0) {
  posX = 500;
}
```

To get your x coordinate back to 500.

Comment: it did work, but still, for some reason, the circle is appearing on the top left for a moment when the loop repeats

Comment: My mistake, the if condition needs to be <=, otherwise y returns to 0 before x returns to 500, so you see a flash at 0,0